# Multiline \text in an equation

Tags: equations

There are a number of possibilities to have multiline equations, but I am looking for multiline `\text{...}` elements.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a^3 + b^3 \neq c^3 \text{ I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this,\\which this margin is too narrow to contain.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to break that long text into two lines? The `\\` does not work here.

Comment: A text as long like this is normally placed outside of mathmode. Only fillwords, like `and`, `where`, `or` are placed inside mathmode to concatenate the various terms. Also, please always provide a fully featured [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), your question are highly more likely to get answered then.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will update it into a full MWE.  I am aware that `\text` is meant rather for short annotations, but sometimes I feel it's better to put the text there than in an `\intertext` or in a footnote.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Remarks

To reserve a box for text of a given size, use the `\parbox` macro.

```
\parbox[position]{width}{text}
```

- `position` (optional): LaTeX will position the box, such that its center lines up with the surrounding text. Possible values can be `t` or `b`
- `width` (mandatory): Specifies the width. The width needs a unit like `em`, `cm`, `ex`, etc...
- `text` (can be empty): Your text, of course.

**Keep in mind, that multiline text inside a box needs to be fit into the paragraph and therefore heavily disrupts your spacing!**

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    a^3 + b^3 \neq c^3 \; \parbox{15em}{I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this,\\which this margin is too narrow to contain.}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: love the example!