# write a small text in an equation environment after the symbol "="

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I wanto to write something like this

```
c dt = average probability that a particular 1-2
       molecular pair will react according to R
       in the next infinitesimal time interval dt.
```

I tried with \\ but it does not work. 
How can I do such a thing?

Comment: potential duplicate: [Multiline `\text` in an equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125917/579)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different way not shown in Barbara's suggested alternative.  Here, the text is explicitly broken with a end-of-line delimiters, whereas the `\parbox` alternative is flushed to a box of specified size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\begin{document}
\[
c\,dt = \Longunderstack[l]{average probability that a particular 1-2\cr
       molecular pair will react according to $R$\cr
       in the next infinitesimal time interval $dt$.}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]