# Putting side-notes and cross-referencing equations within align environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, align

Here I need to number only one equation in the first `align` environment in the MWE. I tried it with `align*`, numbered the equation with `\tag`. But then cross-referencing was not working properly.

To give side-notes I am using `\tag*{}`. But the problem appeared when I am adding a label by `\label{eq:1}` and side-note by `\tag*{ [ Using some formulas] }`. Because it gives the whole sidenote `[ Using some formulas ]` when I mention it later as `\eqref{eq:1}`. But I don't want that. I want to display the `\eqref{eq:1}` as an equation number.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{fphw_assignment_toc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}                              
\usepackage[sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}      
\usepackage[
     hidelinks,                      % remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks 
     bookmarksopen,                  % for PDF specific display option
     bookmarksnumbered,              % for PDF specific display option
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}                     
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}     
%........................
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    P &= ......................................... \nonumber \\
  % some lines of equations
    &=  .........................................\label{eq:1} \tag*{ [ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. ] }  \\
      &= ......................................... \nonumber \\
   % some lines of equations  
    \implies P &\approx ......................................... \tag*{ [ Using \eqref{eq:2} on \eqref{eq:1} ] } \nonumber
\end{align}
\newpage
\lipsum
\begin{align}
      z = ......................................... \label{eq:2} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want to have an output like:

```
          P = ......................................... 
            = .........................................         
                   [ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. ]   (1)
            = .........................................   
       ⇒ P ≈ .........................................      [ Using (2) on (1) ] 
\newpage ...
\lipsum ...
               z = .........................................                       (2)
```

For sidenotes, I have tried using `\text{}` instead of `\tag*{}`. But it crosses the right margin when the sidenote is long. I don't want that either. Is it possible to allow auto-break lines in `\text{}` and align it properly with the available space? Also, I have noticed, if I click on `\eqref{eq:2}` on pdf, it doesn't take me exactly at `\label{eq:2}`.

When is the most efficient way to handle these issues?

Comment: For your MWE, it's best you condense it to the minimum needed to replicate the problem/idea. Also it's best to include the preamble (starting from `\documentclass`) so we can just copy&paste your code to try some things.

Comment: Kindly check it now.

Comment: Please, be so kind and reduce your document example to an MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem, In it the most of packages in your document example is not needed.

Comment: I have reduced my package sections. Hope it's okay now.

Comment: Okay but where one can find the class file `fphw_assignment_toc.cls` used in your document? Meanwhile, There is no problem with `article` class.

Comment: @ferahfeza, sorry. Now I have added the GitLab link of the class file.

Comment: This question addresses this same situation: [Multiline `\text` in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125917).  The only thing I'd add is that the `[t]` option to `\parbox` should be considered.  (Possible duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\parbox[t]{2cm}{a long text..}
```

to allow linebreaking but a more standard and better looking layout would be to not put long comments there and place them in normal text before or after the alignment or in `\intertext` between the lines of an alignment.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Is there any way to adjust the width of the `\parbox` automatically with the available space? Also, can I align the `\intertext` at the right?

Comment: @raf 1 not easily, 2 \raggedleft

Comment: Thank you, but `\raggedleft \intertext` doesn't produce my desired output. I am satisfied with `\parbox`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double `&&` for alignment the `text` in `align` environment instead of `\tag`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}                              
\usepackage[sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}      
\usepackage[
     hidelinks,                      % remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks 
     bookmarksopen,                  % for PDF specific display option
     bookmarksnumbered,              % for PDF specific display option
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}                     
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}     
%........................
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    P &= \cdots \nonumber \\
  % some lines of equations
    &= \cdots \label{eq:1} &\qquad &\text{ [ Using some formulas ]}  \\
      &= \cdots \nonumber \\
   % some lines of equations  
    \implies P &\approx \cdots   &\qquad &\text{ [ Using \eqref{eq:2} on \eqref{eq:1} ] } \nonumber
\end{align}
\newpage
\lipsum
\begin{align}
      z = \cdots \label{eq:2} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at making MWE. Kindly check my updated one. Check it with your `\text{}`. 
You will see `\text{}` crosses the right margin for long side-notes. Is it possible to allow auto-break lines in `\text{}` and align it properly with the available space?